# Is there a better way to convert Kotlin List<DataTypeA> to List<DataTypeB>?

Tags: android, collections, kotlin

I'm currently doing the following:

```
fun fromDataListA(list: List<DataTypeA>): List<DataTypeB> {

    val convertedList = mutableListOf<DataTypeB>()

    list.forEach({ data ->
        convertedList.add(DataTypeB().fromDataTypeA(data))
    })
    return convertedList
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what [`map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) is for:

```
val listA : List<DataTypeA> = listOf( ... )
val listB : List<DataTypeB> = listA.map { DataTypeB().fromDataTypeA(it) }
```

Given a type A and B, you can map A to B by supplying a function that takes in a parameter of type A, and returns an instance of type B.